# Ringtone help in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, ringtone

I'm relatively new to Eclipse and Android activities in general. I'm making an android application that handles incoming calls. But when I simulate a call, it does not play any sound, and in the Sound settings, the only option is 'Silent'. I want to set a ringtone for the simulator. Can someone help me out here? I'm using Eclipse Juno, with an 4.1 platform, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a BROADCAST service to know the status of telephony: RING, HANGUP etc.

**Basically to play a ring tone example:**

```
{

Context context = this; //or getBaseContext() depend where you execute the code
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
r.play();

}
```